# Contract class should be an abstract class

Tags: c#-4.0, abstract-class, code-contracts

The following code gives me the warning `Contract class 'FooContracts' should be an abstract class`. From all the examples I've read online (e.g. http://www.infoq.com/articles/code-contracts-csharp), this should work (presumably without compiler warnings).

```
[ContractClass(typeof(FooContracts))]
public interface IFoo {
  void Bar(string foo);
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IFoo))]
internal sealed class FooContracts : IFoo {
  void IFoo.Bar(string foo) {
    Contract.Requires(foo != null);
  }
}
```

I'm in Visual Studio 2010, with the following settings in the `Code Contracts` section of the project's properties:

- Perform Runtime Contract Checking (set to `Full`)
- Perform Static Contract Checking (under `Static Checking`)
- Check in Background

I also defined the `CONTRACTS_FULL` compilation symbol to make ReSharper shut up.

Am I missing something to make this compile without warnings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Section 2.8 of the [code contracts manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf) specifically states that it should be an abstract class:

> The tools expect that the contract class is abstract and implements the interface it is providing contracts
>   for.

Comment: huh. thanks for the link. that fact was never mentioned nor demonstrated in any example code i found.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the InfoQ article you are referencing is incorrect. It's based on an "early access" edition of C# in Depth, so the code contracts implementation probably changed between the time the chapter/article was originally written and .NET 4 was released.

The following code should work:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(FooContracts))] 
public interface IFoo { 
  void Bar(string foo); 
} 

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IFoo))] 
internal abstract class FooContracts : IFoo { 
  void IFoo.Bar(string foo) { 
    Contract.Requires(foo != null); 
  } 
}
```

The contract class must be abstract.

Comment: But making the class abstract means you can't new it after you implement the interface :( Any alternative around this? Other that creating a new concrete class that inherits from the abstract class?

Comment: @MnemonicFlow You shouldn't be creating instances of the contract class anyway.  It's only for use by the Code Contracts engine.